# Is there any Glade3 installer for Windows?

Tags: windows, installation, gtk, glade

I downloaded file:

http://downloads.sourceforge.net/gladewin32/glade-3.4.3-win32-1.zip

and when I extract it an run glade-3.exe from /bin folder, I get "no libxml2.dll" error.

Now, I want to find installer (like [GTK+ bundle](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/gtk+/2.14/gtk+-bundle_2.14.7-20090119_win32.zip) for GTK+) that would install glade3 and **all** it's dependencies for Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

Well glade3 worked for me after I downloaded:

- iconv.dll
- libxml2.dll

and put it in path

This is not the answer, but it can help run it.

Another thing. I previously installed GTK+ bundle, so if you didn't do that, you may need more dll's etc...

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, the newer version available at http://downloads.sourceforge.net/gladewin32/ is an installer that already includes libxml.